# What does Type * foo() mean/return?

Tags: c, function, binary-search-tree, treenode, dynamic-function

I am implementing a Binary Search Tree. And it so happens one of my sources have a function written such that:

```
Node * BST_Insert(Node *root, int val)
{
//Body 
}
```

I already know that a pointer is a variable which contains the address of another variable and we can't assign a value to a pointer, but we can assign the address of another variable to the pointer.

My Question is what the pointers on this prototype do exactly?

```
Node * BST_Insert(Node *root,int val)
```

Comment: `Node * BST_Insert(Node *root,"") ` is not a valid C in this context. Did you accidentally replace `int val` with `""`?

Comment: The pointers do nothing, the prototype is just a declaration of your function. What is your question? Also please address the first comment and [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` is most likely a `typedef` of a structure representing a node in the Binary Search Tree.

Thus `Node *root` represents a pointer to the root of the BST, i.e. a handle to the tree structure.

Since insertion of a new node may change which node is the root of the tree, the function most likely returns a pointer to the new root node.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are saying it's  similar to rewriting it as **Node BST_Insert(Node *root, int val){return *root)** instead of **Node *BST_Insert(Node *root, int val){return root}**?

Comment: @HilarioNengare No, in the first case `BST_Insert()` would make a copy of the node pointed at by `root` and return that copy. Hence we would have 2 copies of the node. In the second case, `BST_Insert()` simply returns the pointer to the already existing node.

Comment: First case would return a copy , second case just returns a pointer to the original node. Understood. You are my hero! And FYI I tried my notion but it threw this **[Error] incompatible types when returning type 'Node' {aka 'struct Node'} but 'Node *' {aka 'struct Node *'} was expected** Now I understand fully and thanks again @nielsen

Answer (score 0):

The Pointer is pointing at the address of the returned data, In this case your function returns a Node data type. For example if your function was returning an array you can declare it as Function Pointer to have access to the address of the returned array

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not make much sense. This function does not return a "Node data type", but a pointer to a Node. A function returning an array could be declared with a pointer to the array as its return type. A [Function Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) is something else.